# What is the tag in HTML that refer to element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, arguments

In line8:- it has element.parentElement.remove(element), here the element it refers to what tag in HTML?

Note:- This the [fiddle](https://repl.it/@hamzhsami/thisparentElement) code, in case you need it.

**Javascript**

```
    var td4 = document.createElement('td'); 
              td4.setAttribute("id", "td4");
              td4.innerHTML = <button 
             onclick=remove(this.parentElement)>X</button> *line4
              tr.appendChild(td4);

    function remove(element){
             element.parentElement.remove(element) **line8**
    }
```

****HTML****

```
<div class='table'>
    <table id="table">
        <th>
             <tr>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Urgency</td>
                <td>Done</td>
            </tr>
        </th>
        <button onclick=clearAll()> Clear All </button>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s neither valid HTML nor valid JavaScript. Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/). Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser to find out what each expression refers to. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: Still not right. If I were you, I'd just use Stack Snippets (icon is `<>` in the toolbar, [more info here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)) and be sure to click Run code snippet to make sure in runs as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
// You'll need to access to the tr element.
// Also, I would recommend use const instead of var
const tr = document.querySelector('tr');
const td4 = document.createElement('td'); 
td4.setAttribute("id", "td4");
// You'll need to use the parentElement property twice, because the button will be inserted into the 'td' and you need access to the 'tr'
td4.innerHTML = `<button 
onclick=remove(this.parentElement.parentElement)>X</button>`
tr.appendChild(td4);

function remove(element){
  element.parentElement.remove(element)
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
    <table id="table">
        <th>
             <tr>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Urgency</td>
                <td>Done</td>
            </tr>
        </th>
        <button onclick=clearAll()> Clear All </button>
    </table>
</div>
```

Read more about Accessing the DOM [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction#How_Do_I_Access_the_DOM.3F).

Comment: But why I need to add this.parentElement twice, my code working with one parentElement.

Answer (score 0):

element in `element.parentElement.remove(element)` is `td4`.
You should add `console` to print the tag easily.

```
    function remove(element){
       console.log(element);
       element.parentElement.remove(element) **line8**
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Okay and the second thing is in **line8**, what the tag that refers to the **parentElement** in HTML.
I try to console the parentElement , but it keeps shows that **parentElement** is *undefined*.

Comment: like what? `console.log(element.parentElement)`@HamzaSAMI

Comment: No, like this I mean console.log(parentElement).

Comment: Try add this `console.log(element.parentElement)` in your function `remove`, because it's not defined in the function. @HamzaSAMI